# Issues editing y axis on curve plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, yaxis

I'm trying to stack multiple log curves on a single graph. I've managed to get them to stack, however I cannot seem to edit the y axis limits despite trying ", `ylims(0,35)`", "+ `ylims(0, 35)`", or any iteration of `coord_cartesian()`, `lims()`, or `scale_y_continuous()`. If I do manage to get R to notice I've put a modifier in, it pops up an error

> cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'character'.

A chunk of my current code is:

```
eqn_1=function(x){0.8372*log(x)+10.204}
eqn_2=function(x){1.2955*log(x)+9.1096}

curve(eqn_1, from=1, to=27, n=100, xlab="X", ylab="Y", col="blue", lwd=2, main="Title")
curve(eqn_2, from=1, to=27, n=100, add=TRUE, xlab="X", ylab="Y", col="red", lwd=2, main="Title")
```

I have tried all aforementioned approaches on a single graph (say, that of eqn_1) and still cannot get it to work, and when I try plotting multiple lines on the same plot it does not rescale- it simply cuts anything above the top threshold off.

I have tried:

```
curve(eqn_1, from=1, to=27, n=100, xlab="X", ylab="Y", col="blue", lwd=2, main="Title", ylim(0,35)) 
# and the plot does not change

curve(eqn_1, from=1, to=27, n=100, xlab="X", ylab="Y", col="blue", lwd=2, main="Title" + ylim(0,35)) 
# same, plot does not change

curve(eqn_1, from=1, to=27, n=100, xlab="X", ylab="Y", col="blue", lwd=2, main="Title") + ylim(0,35)
# plot does not change
```

```
curve(eqn_1, from=1, to=27, n=100, xlab="X", ylab="Y", col="blue", lwd=2, main="Title") + lims(y = c(0,35))
```

> error: non-numeric argument to binary operator

```
curve(eqn_1, from=1, to=27, n=100, xlab="X", ylab="Y", col="blue", lwd=2, main="Title") + lims(y = (0,35))
```

> error: unexpected ',' in ...

Comment: `curve` is a base R plot. You are trying to change the axes with `ggplot` functions. They are not compatible. See `?curve` and `?axis`

Comment: Thank you, will attempt!

Answer (score 1):

The way to edit the y-axis limits with the base R `curve()` function is with the `ylim =` argument. Supply this argument with a numeric vector, length 2, with the y-axis limits. Use `xlim = c()` to set the x-axis limits.

```
eqn_1=function(x){0.8372*log(x)+10.204}
eqn_2=function(x){1.2955*log(x)+9.1096}

curve(eqn_1, from=1, to=27, n=100, xlab="X", ylab="Y", col="blue", 
      lwd=2, main="Title", ylim = c(0,35))
curve(eqn_2, from=1, to=27, n=100, add=TRUE, xlab="X", ylab="Y", col="red", 
      lwd=2, main="Title", ylim = c(0,35))
```

[image]